# Check if the values of Dictionary<DateTime, List<ClassA>> has a specific type of ClassA using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have this Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<ClassA>> Delivery { get; set; }
```

and ClassA is defined like this:

```
public class ClassA
{       
    public string abc{ get; set; }
    public long Size{ get; set; }
    .....
}
```

I wanna check using linq, if the dictionary has string abc != string.empty

so I'm looking for sth like this:

```
Delivery.Where(x => x.ClassB.classA.Values.Any(i => !String.isNullOrEmpty(i.abc))
```

but it's not compiling, how can I do this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over `KeyValuePair` items from your dictionary in the `.Where` statement, so you are getting an error because `ClassB` is not a property of `KeyValuePair`.

Something like the code below should do the trick. In the code, `x` represents an item from `Delivery` (which is a `KeyValuePair` type). The `Key` of `x` is of type `DateTime` (which we're not concerned about), and the `Value` of `x` is of type `List<ClassA>`, which is what we're looking for.

So, `x.Value` is a `List<ClassA>`, which means we can call `Any` on that list and look at each list item (represented by `v`, which is of type `ClassA`) and see if it has a null or empty `abc` property:

```
var hasItemWithEmptyAbc = Delivery.Any(x => x.Value.Any(v => string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.abc)));
```

This will return a Boolean that is `true` if any item in the dictionary has any null or empty `.abc` property of a `ClassA` in the item's `List<ClassA>`

If you want to get all the items that have a list that contains a `ClassA` with an empty `abc` property, the following will give you a list of `KeyValuePair<DateTime, List<ClassA>>`:

```
var itemsWithEmptyAbc = Delivery
    .Where(x => x.Value.Any(v => string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.abc)))
    .ToList();
```

Or, if you want to get just the items themselves (the `ClassA` instances that have an empty `abc` property, you could do something like this:

```
var classAsWithEmptyAbc = Delivery
    .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.abc)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Originally I had it like how you have but I wanted to assign it to a variable and read from the values, that's why I used Where. The problem was that the compiler was not recognizing field abc since field abc was actually the value of a dictionary in class A and that value was a list so I had to another Any() on that.

Comment: Oh, I see. I added a few more ways to pull in the data. One to get a list of all the `KeyValuePair` objects whose `List<ClassA>` contains a `ClassA` with an empty `.abc`, and another that just gets the `ClassA` objects with an empty `.abc`.